# Sitecore Analytics Profiling Tab No Value

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-analytics

I've created a profile with its profile key + cards in sitecore that will be assigned to the item.. Then in mongoDB the value is already filled

[image: mongodb value]

I also change the pattern cards to have same value with mongodb

[image: value pattern cards]

But in experience editor there is nothing in profiling tab and the best pattern not found

[image: sitecore profiling 1]
[image: sitecore profiling 2]